Kivy - Weird keyboard_suggestions behavior on Android
I have set Keyboard_suggestions to True and the input_type to "text" for both TextInputs. To produce the bug I wrote "Test" into the first Textinput (without using the suggestions). After that I clicked on the second Field and pressed "1". Somehow what I wrote previousely was pasted into the second InputField after I pressed "1".Video of the issue
Code from the Video:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App


KV = """
BoxLayout:
 orientation: "vertical"
 TextInput:
  input_type:'text'
  keyboard_suggestions:True
 TextInput:
  input_type:'text'
  keyboard_suggestions:True
"""

class Test(App):
 def build(self):
  return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()

main.py
I guess that the keyboard suggestions are not reset when switching between widgets. Because when you unfocus the first widget (by pressing the minimize keyboardbutton on the bottom right or by clicking outside of the Textinput) and then focus/click on the second Textinput, it will work correctly.
My current solution is, that on_focus if focus, I will unfocuse and directly focus the widget again, this fixes the issue, but the keyboard will flash up 2 times. Video of the solution
Is there a better solution or a way to avoid this bug?

Add enough code to your question as to make a minimal reproducible example.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@MUFF. I was able to reproduce the bug with the code mentioned in the question.
